# Send SMS from an app with no UI

Tags: ios4

Does anyone know how to send an SMS from the xcode application without using the UI?
I mean I want the SMS to be sent internally from the application. I have seen an app that has this feature.

I have alarm system, the alarm only receive SMS nothing else, I need the user to see the alarm name that is easy, but I want the user to choose the alarm name and control it (close, open) and I need to send command by SMS that the issue, the user should not see the alarm number neither the content which is the command text if you can help me that I will pay anyone that can help me with this.

I'm developing on iOS version 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

no there is no way to do it in background , you have to call the GUI unless you create your api that ask for no & send sms from server.

Comment: Okay then can I set the recipents from text field and I want to have button called login, when he press it I want to send SMS, i dont want the send button attached in the keyboard neither the send, I want them to be in the view, is there is way to do that??? please help

Comment: Can I attach the send Button that cames by default with SMSUI to custom button that I have in the view, is because I am developing an alarm controll application that takes number and password and then I will send in the body command to open or close the user should not see this command.

Comment: yes you can set recipient  MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        NSString *bodyString = nil;

        NSMutableArray *toRecipients = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [toRecipients addObject:@"0933660805"];
        [picker setRecipients:(NSArray *)toRecipients];
        [toRecipients release];

        bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Message body"];
        [picker setBody:bodyString];,

Comment: but i think there is no way to rename sent to login and you should also not to do this else there is a change to reject your app form appstore.

Comment: I have alarm system, the alarm only recieve SMS nothing else, I need the user to see the alarm name that is easy, but I want the user to chooce the alarm name and control it(close, opem) and I need to send command by SMS that the issue, the user should not see the alarm number neither the content which is the command text if you can help me that I will pay you for this... please.

Comment: want to help you but not exactly getting what you want.. how you are getting alarm and all that

Comment: I am getting the alarm info via the wifi but the alarm comands is only reognized by SMS.

Comment: do you mean that you are getting alarm as SMS